# Dynamic progress bar for options menu in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, progress-bar

In Python - How to make the progress bar dynamic? (changes if options menu selected)
for example, If I select one option in the pl1 (pick List) the progress bar will change (let's say 20% progress).

so far I tried:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar

pets= {'Cat', 'Dog', 'Fish'}

def __init__(self):

    root =Tk()
    root.title('window')
    root.geometry('1300x690')
    root.resizable(False, False)

    progress = Progressbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='determinate')
    progress.place(x=500, y=15)

    var1 = StringVar(root)
    pl1 = OptionMenu(root, var1, *self.pets)

    pl1.config(width=20, bg="GREEN", fg="white")
    pl1.place(x=470, y=230)

    #Here I want to add 20% progress to the bar if var1 has been selected (no matter what is the 
    value).

    root.mainloop()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `var1.trace("w", callback)`?

Comment: @TheLizzard what do you mean? To add an IF statement and then what you wrote? Not sure what is the callback..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```py
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
import tkinter as tk


def callback(*args):
    # Increment the progressbar's value by 20%
    progressbar["value"] += 20

root = tk.Tk()

progressbar = Progressbar(root, orient="horizontal", length=300)
progressbar.pack()

var = tk.StringVar(root)
pl1 = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, *(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
pl1.pack()

# Whenever the value of `var` is changed call callback
var.trace("w", callback)

root.mainloop()
```

I basically trace the value of `var` and when it changes `callback` is called. When `callback` is called it passes in some arguments that we can ignore.

Comment: @User1 Cool, but if you ever want to change the value according to the options selected, then make `progressbar["value"] = int(var.get())*20` andit should give you something that increase/decrease with value selected.